# Route53 point to other url (e.g. API Gateway endpoint)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I have:

1. Route53 Hosted Zone with DNS example.com.
2. API Gateway wiht DNS z8n73n8d123.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.

Now if I want to point, lets say, api.example.com or example.com/api (does not matter) to an API Gateway there are at least few ways to do it:

1. Use an Alias A record in Route53. But before that i need to add BasePathMapping and DomainName attributes to an API Gateway, create a Certificate (which MUST be in us-east-1). Creating certificate in us-east-1 is a deal breaker for me so I can not use it.
2. Redirect using S3 bucket. But this looks like a shameful workaround introduced by AWS itself. Also additional charges would apply by triggering S3 every time a redirect should take place. So it is again a deal breaker for me.
3. Use CNAME record???
4. ???

Are there any other viable solutions how to point some-sub-domain.example.com or example.com/whatever to an api gateway?

Comment: why MUST the certificate be in us-east-1?

Comment: @danimal that's an API Gateway requirement for SSL certificates, because is uses CloudFront behind the scenes.

Comment: Why is "Creating certificate in us-east-1 is a deal breaker"? You are artificially limiting yourself from being able to use SSL on API Gateway and AWS CloudFront.

Comment: My cloudformation stack is eu-west-1. I would have to create separate stacks, reference resources between stacks and regions. This is overcomplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFront's home region (where its control plane APIs are hosted) is us-east-1, and CloudFront provides the "edge-optimized" feature of API Gateway.  This is why -- in "edge-optimized" configuration -- the cert goes in us-east-1, because that's where CloudFront is integrated with Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM).

But if you choose a "regional" API deployment then the certificate goes in ACM in the same region as the API Gateway deployment itself.

See [Set Up a Custom Domain Name for a Regional REST API or WebSocket API in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-regional-api-custom-domain-create.html) in the *Amazon API Gateway Developer Guide*.